# Managing different roles using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles

I'm coding an application about a wireless network using Ruby on Rails. This application is made of different roles: Admin, Employee and Visitor.

The visitor part has been already made by a colleague of mine following Michael Hartl's guide (basically the *user* has been replaced with *visitor*) and now I have to do the rest.

Unfortunately she used neither *devise* nor other gems similar to it and I can't demolish all her work, so I can use none of them.

In this applications there are classes such as MACaddress or VLAN and both visitor and employee/admin can do some operations on them, but of course these operations are different (different permissions according to the roles).

Here my main issue comes.
Consider something like this:

```
class MacaddressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_visitor, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_visitor,   only: [:destroy,:update]

  def create
    @macaddresses = current_visitor.macaddresses.build(macaddresses_params)
    if @macaddresses.save
      flash[:success] = "mac address created!"
      redirect_to visitor_path(session[:visitor_id],:act => 'mynetwork')
    else
      @macaddresses = current_visitor.macaddresses.all
      @visitor = current_visitor
      render 'visitors/myNetwork'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @macaddresses.destroy
    redirect_to visitor_path(session[:visitor_id],:act => 'myNetwork',:del=>'true')
  end

  def update
    if @macaddresses.update_attributes(macaddresses_params)
      redirect_to visitor_path(session[:visitor_id],:act => 'myNetwork',:del=>'true')
    else
      @macaddresses = current_visitor.macaddresses.all
      @visitor=current_visitor
      render 'visitors/myNewtork2'
    end
  end
```

Now... how can I define CRUD different operations on MACaddress or other classes according to the user's role?

I created even _current_employee_, how can I use it to do what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your partner turned User into Visitor, does that mean that you now have to have an Admin model for admin users and an Employee model for employee users?

Comment: Exactly, in fact I created the Employee model with its controller, its views and so on. But I have problems when I have to define CRUD operations on other models in common: for example in the code above CRUD operations on macaddress are defined using the visitor, but how can I define them using the employee? May I use current_employee which keeps track of the user and add some if/else in these methods?

Comment: Your partner made changes without looking to the future at all. `User` should never have been changed to `Visitor`. Instead, `User` should have had a `role` column added, which would make branching on roles trivial. You can keep most of what your partner did, but `Visitor` is going to have to be reverted to `User` -- it's not worth jumping through three thousand flaming hoops in order to avoid admitting a mistake in planning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are nesting routes like this:

```
'/visitors/visitor_id/macaddresses'
```

you could get instance of the user role class like this

```
def find_user_role
  params.each do |name, value|
   next unless name =~ /(.+)_id$/
   user_role_model = $1.classify.constantize rescue nil
   @current_user_role = user_role_model.find(value) if user_role_model
  end
end
```

then you can do

```
@current_user_role.macaddresses.build(macaddress_params).
```

You would probably want to define belongs_to user as polymorphic association in macaddress model too.